# What is toString() and why is it different from this.toString()?

Tags: javascript

Calling `toString()` returns `"[object Undefined]"`, while `this.toString()` returns `"[object Window]"`.
This is according to code run in Chrome 87 and Firefox 84.

My intuition dictates `toString()` is the same as `this.toString()` with `this` part omitted, but the behaviour I'm seeing goes against this.  What language feature of Javascript / ECMAScript governs this difference?  Is it something special to `toString()`?

The following code was used to check the behaviour of each browser.  In IE 11 it was `"[object Window]"` for all.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
console.log("toString() = " + toString())
console.log("toString.call() = " + toString.call())

console.log("this.toString() = " + this.toString())
console.log("toString.call(this) = " + toString.call(this))
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: In your first example you use the method `toString()` without defining what you are using it on. In your second example you use the method `toString()` on `this` which in the global scope (in a browser) points to the `Window` object.

Comment: See [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429) - in short, when you call `toString()` by itself, it's implicitly taken from `window` (the global object) but the invocation doesn't pass a `this` value. So, it's effectively equivalent to `window.toString.call(undefined)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toString === window.toString` when run in the global context.

The first returns `[object Undefined]` because you're not running the method *on* anything.

You're able to call it **without** `window.` because doing so will cause JavaScript to look for the function first in the local scope then on `window`. But in doing so you're calling it as a standalone function, rather than a method, and a method needs to run *on* something.

Comment: Thanks for this.  This makes a lot of sense after reading the answer linked by VLAZ's [comment to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65594424/what-is-tostring-and-why-is-it-different-from-this-tostring?noredirect=1#comment115972730_65594424) and the linked article by Mike West therein.